# SVG Filter Grayscale to Alpha

Tags: svg

I have an rgb image with various colors and grayish parts (white - grey - black).

Now I would like to transform the grayish pixels to transparent / alpha, whilst keeping the colored pixels as they are.

As of now I am rendering the image on a canvas and then iterate over the pixels. If the channels R, G, B are close for a pixel it turn the pixels alpha to 0.

**Is there a way of doing this via svg filters?**

https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/filters.html

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects-1/#grayscaleEquivalent

Comment: @RobertLongson This is not about colors to grayscale, but about grayscale to alpha whilst keeping the colors.

Comment: You'd still need an feColorMatrix filter, maybe with tableValues